# How to restore entire disk to a prior snapshot made using Shadow Copy using command line program?

Tags: windows-7, volume-shadow-copy, shadow-copy

I am trying to emulate software such as Faronics DeepFreeze using Win7's built-in Shadow Copy functionality.

I am able to create snapshot of entire disk, and I can see that changes are tracked.

Next, I am able to boot into Windows Recovery Environment, and to use restore option to rollback to any prior snapshot.

Now, I am wondering if there's a way to execute some command, give volume and snapshot IDs as arguments, and have partition restored to given snapshot?